# Como consultar o status das transações do PayPal por URL

Tags: php, xml

Existe alguma maneira para retornar informações de uma transação via transação id no PayPal?

**Exemplo** ([API PagSeguro](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/consulta-de-transacoes-por-codigo.html)): https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/281AC601-59B6-40CC-ACFC-62B0CD047B14?email=usuario@servidor.com&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

**O máximo que consegui encontrar foi:** paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=7DJ47958EX567045P

Isso é exatamente o que eu quero, porem, eu preciso em XML ou de uma maneira de pegar as informações com PHP.

Se não for possível exibir as informações em XML, há alguma maneira de obter as informações com PHP?

Comment: Na [API Oficial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) você encontra os métodos (em `PHP` inclusive) para fazer consultas sobre as transações. Porém o retorno é `JSON` como diz aqui _`Request and response payloads are formatted as JSON`_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problema resolvido!

Para quem está tendo algum problema relacionado, recomendo o uso da biblioteca criada pelo **Andrew Angell**: https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/

No meu caso, eu estou usando CodeIgniter, e usei a biblioteca já integrada do mesmo: https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-codeigniter-class-library-for-paypal/